# what is Internal working of Authorize attribute in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

How does the AuthorizeAttribute work?

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AuthenticatedUsers()
{
    return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
public ActionResult AdministratorsOnly()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It like be a Session

```
[Authorize] means if allow all authenticated users

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")] means if allow only roles person
```

for example admin see everything in page, but same page user see some content.